# How to access nested Repeaters in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to fill the colours in the following rectangles created through Repeaters, **dynamically**.

I am not able to access the bottom Repeater at all.

***How should I access "all" the rectangles here?***

```
        Row
        {
            spacing: 20
            Repeater
            {
                id: repeater3

                property Repeater repeater2: repeater2

                model: head.rows
                Column
                {
                    id: columnInBetween
                    spacing: 20
                    Repeater
                    {
                        id: repeater2
                        model: head.columns
                        property Row row1: row1
                        Row
                        {
                            id: row1
                            property Repeater repeater1: repeater1
                            Repeater
                            {
                                id: repeater1
                                model: 2
                                Rectangle
                                {
                                    width: 20; height: 20
                                    color: "red" 
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `I am not able to access the bottom Repeater at all` - Why not? What did you try?

Comment: If you need to access the items created by the repeaters, you can either traverse the `children` property of their parents (remembeer,  Repeater parents what it creates to its own parent -- after itself!) or "register" the items of interest in a property of an item with an id visible at the file scope;

Comment: ...if you are looking for ways to access outer Repeaters' per-item model data, there are ways, too (i.e. "alias" it with smth like `property var modelData2: modelData` -- provided the name of the property Repeater attaches is `modelData` -- don't remember right now, can be plain `model`, these things are a bit inconsistent between Repeater and ListView, iirc).

Answer (score 0):

`Repeater` will expand `Item` they contians.So you can use `.children[index]` to access those `Item` expanded.
In your case:

```
/*0< index < head.rows
you get first Column expanded by repeater3*/
repeater3.itemAt(index).children[0]

/*0< index < head.columns
you get first Row of first Column expanded by repeater3 and repeater2*/
repeater3.itemAt(index).children[0].children[0]

/*0< index < 2
you get first Rectangle of first Row of first Column expanded by repeater3 and repeater2 and repeater1*/
repeater3.itemAt(index).children[0].children[0].children[0]
```

By the way, I do not know your intention and just remaid that you are getting a **head.columns** rows and **2 * head.rows** columns of tables.